# Get 403 on an unrestricted location

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403

Got 403 for this page :

```
Alias /nconf /usr/local/nconf/
<Directory "/usr/local/nconf">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.1.1.0/8
</Directory>
```

My ip is 10.1.1.132 so have to work.
Don't know why but my error log don't log any problem. My access log nor. I use virtualhost but this page is on the main, who is defined like :

```
ErrorLog logs/error_log
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
```

I don't know what to do...

Comment: can't see where is my problem...